# JQuery and printArea — customizing print output

Tags: jquery, printing

I'm printing a content from a block via printArea plugin. I'm able to customize doc styles etc., but still I can't get a workaround on my problem.

How to hide/disable the common running titles (which contain a path to doc file, date and page in a `page n of m` format) from header/bottom of the document?

I'm using a native `Print to file` printer of Ubuntu, if it can give any clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a *browser* setting, not one that JavaScript (and so not jQuery either) can touch, you'll need to go into your print properties to change it.